# How to marshall java.lang.Exception using JAXB Marshaller?

Tags: java, jaxb, marshalling

I am trying to marshall java.lang.Exception, but without success. Here's my code -

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBException;
import javax.xml.bind.Marshaller;

public class JAXBTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
       TestReport report = new TestReport();
       report.setReportLog("Tests successful.");

       File file = new File("TestReport.xml");
       JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(TestReport.class);
       Marshaller jaxbMarshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();

       jaxbMarshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
       jaxbMarshaller.marshal(report, file);
    }
}
```

This is the class I want to marshall -

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class TestReport
{
    private String reportLog;
    private Exception exception;

    @XmlElement
    public void setReportLog(String reportLog) { this.reportLog = reportLog; }

    public String getReportLog() { return reportLog; }

    @XmlElement
    public void setException(Exception exception) { this.exception = exception; }

    public Exception getException() { return exception; }

}
```

I get the following exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException: 1 counts of IllegalAnnotationExceptions
java.lang.StackTraceElement does not have a no-arg default constructor.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at java.lang.StackTraceElement
        at public java.lang.StackTraceElement[] java.lang.Throwable.getStackTrace()
        at java.lang.Throwable
        at java.lang.Exception
        at public java.lang.Exception TestReport.getException()
        at TestReport

    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.IllegalAnnotationsException$Builder.check(IllegalAnnotationsException.java:91)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.getTypeInfoSet(JAXBContextImpl.java:451)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:283)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl.<init>(JAXBContextImpl.java:126)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.runtime.JAXBContextImpl$JAXBContextBuilder.build(JAXBContextImpl.java:1142)
    at com.sun.xml.internal.bind.v2.ContextFactory.createContext(ContextFactory.java:130)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:248)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.newInstance(ContextFinder.java:235)
    at javax.xml.bind.ContextFinder.find(ContextFinder.java:445)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:637)
    at javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext.newInstance(JAXBContext.java:584)
    at JAXBTester.main(JAXBTester.java:14)
```

This is because I am trying to marshall java.lang.Exception. How to solve this problem?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1241551/how-do-you-serialize-an-exception-subclass-in-jaxb) for a possible solution to a similar problem.

Comment: @Pyranja, I saw that one before. It is for subclasses of java.lang.Exception.

Comment: That's true but you can apply the solution to the serialization of Exception itself too. The problem is, that a part of the Throwable class (parent of all exceptions) can not be serialized due to the lack of a no-arg constructor (it is the StackElement). To avoid this you have to exclude the stackelements from the serialization. The linked question shows how to do that, as you can't modify the Throwable class itself.

Answer (score 1):

There are other ways of doing it, such as the one referenced by the commenter.  But here's another way...

The `Throwable` class in Java (superclass of `Exception`) is serializable in the sense of `java.io.Serializable`.  This means that you can write it to a byte stream and then recompose it later from those bytes.  (It's possible that your application might have poorly-written non-serializable subclasses of `Throwable`.  If that's the case, the following won't work.)

So one way to deal with this is to write a custom adapter that serializes the `Throwable` (or `Exception`) to bytes.  And in the XML, you see the hex for those bytes.  Then on the receiving end you can un-serialize and then work with (an exact replica of) the `Throwable` you started with.

The bad part about this way is that the Exception is not human-readable inside the XML.  The good part is that it's really simple.  On your `TestReport` class, put this annotation on your `Exception` getter:

```
@XmlJavaTypeAdapter(ThrowableAdapter.class)
public Exception getException() { return exception; }

public void setException(Exception exception) { this.exception = exception; }
```

And then add this adapter class to your project:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.HexBinaryAdapter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;

public class ThrowableAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Throwable> {
    private HexBinaryAdapter hexAdapter = new HexBinaryAdapter();

    @Override
    public String marshal(Throwable v) throws Exception {
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(baos);
        oos.writeObject(v);
        oos.close();
        byte[] serializedBytes = baos.toByteArray();
        return hexAdapter.marshal(serializedBytes);
    }

    @Override
    public Throwable unmarshal(String v) throws Exception {
        byte[] serializedBytes = hexAdapter.unmarshal(v);
        ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(serializedBytes);
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(bais);
        Throwable result = (Throwable) ois.readObject();
        return result;
    }
}
```

Then your XML will contain an element like this:

```
<exception>AED...</exception>
```

except in instead of `...` you'll see a huge hex string.  When it's un-marshalled on the other side, it'll be just like the original.

Comment: Better solution if it is important to transport the complete exception object. Nice!

Comment: Unfortunately this solution does not work if your exception encapsulate an object that is not serializable.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use JRE 1.7? I do not get this exception if I use JAXB version that is distributed with the JRE. However, if I include explicitly JAXB v. 2.1.7, I run into this problem. Therefore, I'd recommend getting rid of all the jaxb instances from your classpath and use the one that is included in the Java runtime.

JRE 6 seems to use 2.1.x, while JRE 7 2.2.x, which probably handles the change in Throwable implementation correctly.

The JAXB version included in your JDK can be found by running

```
<JDK_HOME>/bin/xjc -version
```